# why mb-button ripple effect vanishing on applying ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-material

i am using angular material for my ionic app,i used `<md-button>` directive for material design,all was working fine for me but when i applied the hyper link using `ui-serf` its ripple effect as well as size get destroyed.And also `ui-sref` not working with the `md-button` is it because of ordering of these two directives ?Suggest me the better way to do.

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
            <div  flex>
                <md-button type="button" class="button-full md-raised google-color" style="color:#ffffff" ui-sref="menue.state1" >G+</md-button>
            </div>
            <div  flex>
                <md-button  class="button-full md-raised facebook-color" ng-click="go_to_state('menue.state2')" style="color:#ffffff">Facebook</md-button>
            </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.go_to_state=function(url){
      console.log(url);
      $state.go(url);

    }
```

route on button 1 not working because of ui-sref where as facebook button is working becase i am handling with ng-click.
Why first button is not working and how it will work and why the ripple effect is getting vanished in both the cases.

**Note:** *Its not logging me any error.*

Answer (score 0):

the ui-sref directive is made for link tags `<a>` not for buttons. On your button just use ng-click like on your second button.

Comment: is it the only solution that i can get, how about add like
<md-button type="button" class="button-full md-raised google-color" style="color:#ffffff"  ><a ui-sref="menue.state1">G+</a></md-button>
Why button design getting effected (vanishing ripple effect and shrinking width)

Comment: if you want something special, the angular way to go is build your own directive. Maybe as a starting point look at the mdButton directive here: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.0.0-rc6/src/components/button/button.js